# How does a program determine the size of a file without reading it whole?

Tags: performance, file, filesize

In the question [Using C++ filestreams (fstream), how can you determine the size of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409504/using-c-filestreams-fstream-how-can-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file), the top answer is the following C++ snippet:

```cpp
ifstream file("example.txt", ios::binary | ios::ate);
return file.tellg();
```

Running it myself I noticed that the size of arbitrarily large files could be determined instantaneously and with a *single* read operation.

Conventionally I would assume that to determine the size of a file, one would have to move through it byte-by-byte, adding to a byte-counter. How is this achieved instead? Metadata?

Comment: Isn't the filesize stored as a designated value in file metadata in all conventional filesystems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the file is embedded in the file metadata in the file system. Different file systems have different ways of storing this information.

**Edit** Obviously, this is an incomplete answer. When someone will provide an answer where he'll exemplify on a common filesystem like ex3 or ntfs or fat exactly how the file size it's known and stored, i'll delete this answer.

Comment: Your answer is the most straight forward, i.e. _metadata is being retrieved_.

Answer (score 0):

The file size is stored as metadata on most filesystems. In addition to GI Joe's answer above, you can use the stat function on posix systems:

[stat(3) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat)

```
struct stat     statbuf;
stat("filename.txt", &statbuf);
printf("The file is %d bytes long\n", statbuf.st_size);
```

Answer (score -1):

When `ios::ate` is set, the initial position will be the end of the file, but you are free to seek thereafter.

`tellg` returns the position of the current character in the input stream. The other key part is `ios::binary`.

So all it does it seek to the end of the file for you when it opens the filestream and tell you the current position (which is the end of the file). I guess you could say it's a sort of hack in a way, but the logic makes sense.

If you would like to learn how filestreams work at a lower level, please read this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6066794/2591612).

Comment: This does not answer why the operation is instant.

Comment: Why can you seek to the end of the file without reading it as a whole?

Comment: @usr: You don't need to, just go to the end. You are not "reading it"

Comment: The question is: how does it work? How do you know the end position? If you've got a tape, you don't know how long it is without reading it all. He wants to know about file metadata.

Comment: @usr: That's not the problem. `ios::ate` seeks to the end of stream immediately after open.

Comment: "Conventionally I would assume that to determine the size of a file, one would have to move through it byte-by-byte, adding to a byte-counter. How is this achieved instead? Metadata?" You have not answered this. You just said "just call this API. It is magic.".

Comment: @usr: It's obvious that it is a file stream... just like any other stream. A tape drive is a totally different medium that you have to rewind.

Comment: I know this. He doesn't. He wants this explained. This question might seem trivial but there was a point in time where both of us did not know this either.

Comment: @usr: Ok, I linked to a StackOverflow question that explains it better than I can here.